# Create folders with filenames and move files into folder

Tags: shell

I have a bunch of files that end with `.EHZ` and I am trying to create a folder for each of these files and then move them into the corresponding folders. Also the files have a `Z` attached to the name that I would like to remove. So ideally i would have, for example these files

```
AAAAZBBBBZ.EHZ  
CCCCZDDDDZ.EHZ  
EEEEZFFFFZ.EHZ
```

Turn into the folders

```
AAAABBBB
CCCCDDDD
EEEEFFFF
```

What I have written so far is

```
dir0=pwd
for file in `ls *.EHZ`
do
name=echo $file | head 10
mkdir -p $name
mv "$file" "$name"
done
```

P.S. I have found many answers in stackoverflow that were addressed to this issue but not on shell so I figured I would ask.

Answer (score 2):

Could you please try following. I have used `cp` command for safer side in my code, you could remove it and put it as `mv` in there to actually move files to folders.

```
for file in *.EHZ
do
   name="${file%.*}"
   actual_directory_name="${name::-1}"
   if [[ ! -d "$actual_directory_name" ]]
   then
        mkdir "$actual_directory_name"
   fi
   cp "$file" "$actual_directory_name"
   if [[ -s "$actual_directory_name/$file" ]]
   then
        echo "$file is moved Successfully to directory name $actual_directory_name now.."
   else
        echo "Please check seems $file is NOT moved to directory $actual_directory_name."
   fi
done
```

Comment: With -p flag mkdir won't complain about already existing files.

Comment: It says `line 6: -1: substring expression < 0`

Comment: What system are you working on, I have tried many things but it is not working. I am working on Mac OS Mojave version 10.14.6